# SQLite joining two selects

Tags: sqlite

Any help with this is appreciated

```
(SELECT instance_name, st AS t_2, nd AS d_2
FROM search_comparison 
WHERE instance_path LIKE "%64%" AND nd = '2'
ORDER BY instance_name) AS a 
JOIN
(SELECT instance_name, st AS t_4, nd AS d_4
FROM search_comparison 
WHERE instance_path LIKE "%Set_64%" AND nd = '4'
ORDER BY instance_name) AS b 
ON a.instance_name = b.instance_name
GROUP BY instance_name;
```

The above sqlite query keeps saying syntax error near "(", but I am not able to figure out the reason. I explicitly don't want to do a `Union ALL` because I am trying to get `t_4, d_4, t_2, d_2` as separate columns with `instance_name` being the common column. Also, I can guarantee the column `instance_name` in both the select queries have exactly the same entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a self-join?

```
SELECT
    sc1.nstance_name,
    sc1.st AS t_2,
    sc1.nd AS d_2,
    sc2.st AS t_4,
    sc2.nd AS d_4
FROM search_comparison sc1
INNER JOIN search_comparison sc2
    ON sc1.instance_name = sc2.instance_name
WHERE
    sc1.instance_path LIKE '%64%' AND
    sf1.nd = '2' AND
    sc2.instance_path LIKE '%Set_64%' AND
    sc2.nd = '4';
```

Comment: I actually want the the `nd=2` and `nd=4` and t_2 and the other st as separate columns by using instance_name as the common column to both. Hence, I was trying to do an inner join. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Check my updated answer, perhaps you just want a self join.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Can I actually recurse this statement - like say for 'nd = 6' and so on?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "recurse" here.  Off the top of my head, you could place just the self-join into a CTE, and then select from it based on `nd` values.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the join is this:

```
SELECT a.instance_name, b.t_4, b.d_4, a.t_2, a.d_2 
FROM (
  SELECT instance_name, st AS t_2, nd AS d_2
  FROM search_comparison 
  WHERE instance_path LIKE "%64%" AND nd = '2'
) AS a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT instance_name, st AS t_4, nd AS d_4
  FROM search_comparison 
  WHERE instance_path LIKE "%Set_64%" AND nd = '4'
) AS b ON a.instance_name = b.instance_name
ORDER BY a.instance_name
```

the ORDER BY clause is needed only once at the end.
You also have a `GROUP BY` clause, but it is not clear in your code what you want to aggregate.